# understanding file input output

Tags: java, file-io, tokenize

hi i have some problem understanding my lecture material and thought maybe someone here can help me understand it a bit better

this is the example i have in lecture

```
private void readFileExample (String inFilename){
    FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
    InputStreamReader rdr;
    BufferedReader bufRdr;
    int lineNum;
    String line;
    try {
        fileStrm = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);

        lineNum = 0;
        line = bufRdr.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            lineNum++;
            processLine(line);
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
        }
        fileStrm.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        if (fileStrm != null) {
            try { fileStrm.close(); } catch (IOException ex2) { }
        }
        System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

also i have a slide on parsing csv files

```
private void processLine(String csvRow) {
    String thisToken = null;
    StringTokenizer strTok;
    strTok = new StringTokenizer(csvRow, ",");

    while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {

        thisToken = strTok.nextToken();
        System.out.print(thisToken + " ");

    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

i guess the processLine method is used in readFileExample to seperate the csv file is that right?

and also if my understanding is correct, im supposed to input a file name somewhere and call that into readFileExample but how would i do that, can i use

```
Scanner sc = new scanner (system.in)
filename = sc.nextline()
```

and if its not too much a simple example would be great

thanks for the help.

Comment: From the [documentation for `StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) - "_`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code_". If **Oracle themselves** tell you not to use it; don't.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how you input file name.

It can go like this: **String fileName = new String("myFileName");**

or the way you have:

**Scanner sc = new scanner (system.in);**

**filename = sc.nextline();**

Then after you set the fileName, pass it to readFileExample:

**readFileExample(filename);// Whatever you get the name from, pass it.**

And processLine function, just like it's name, which is for parse each line. If you want to use this program to implement some sort of file analysis. Just use your structure above. but you have to modify the processLine function.

Comment: for the file itself do i need to include the file location or can i just put it in the same directory as the java file? @Evingle

Comment: FileInputStream(String name)
Creates a FileInputStream by opening a connection to an actual file, the file named by the pathname name in the file system.      https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html.  That two ways you mentioned above, should both work.